# detect newly created files in a remote location using java

Tags: java, file, ftp, creation

I want to detect newly created files in a remote location, so I can process this file (read it, and do some operations on it)

so please, how can I do this using Java 5? (I know it is an old server, but we have problems in upgrading it during recent times)

Note: the way to access the remote file is of our choice depending on the proposed solution (i.e. for example, if the best solution is by using FTP, I'll handle it)

thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the Directory [Watcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

This requires Java 7 and the directory be mounted and visible to the user running the process.

Comment: looks promising, thanks,
but is there anyway to do this using FTP?

Comment: You can use FTP to poll the server's directory but its not very efficient. It is fine to do every few minutes if that is ok. You need to wait until the file has finished being written to of course. ;)

Comment: I tried before to write a file to a remote directory using FTP, but how can I poll the directory?

Comment: You send it a CWD to the directory of interest and then a DIR to get a listing with the file names, lengths and modification date.

Answer (score 1):

Polling with FTP is one way.

An alternative, if you can run some custom code on the remote location, would be to keep a connection open between your client and server (or perform a long-poll) and have the server immediately notify the client of any changes to the files.

Comment: I tried before to write a file to a remote directory using FTP, but how can I poll the directory?

Comment: There's a good library for FTP: http://commons.apache.org/net/  It has  `new FTPClient().listFiles(remote)`. You'd call that in a loop, looking for changes, with `Thread.sleep(millis)` between polls.